# How can I match a specific Top Level Domain with a RegEx?

Tags: regex

I will be given a url, and need to match via a Regular Expression only if the URL ends in a certain top level domain. For instance, only match if the domain name is `.cn`. My idea is `*.cn`.

But it shouldn't match, if the `.cn` substring is not at the end of the domain. For instance:

- cnn.com - no match
- cnn.cn - match
- www.csc.edu.cn/studyinchina/ - match

How can I do that?

Comment: try this one `\.cn$`

Comment: Will URLs always end at the top level domain? What language are you using this in?

Comment: This will be used at a firewall that accepts regular expressions, not inside of a programing language.

Comment: Rohan - close - should have added - Site can be any url - ie www.furniture-china.cn/en-us/

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work fine (just tested your 3 examples though)

```
^(http:\/\/)?(\w*\.)*(cn)(\/.*)?$
```

Before you put it in a firewall please try other urls! I've already added the ones you mentioned as unit tests in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UPBMbG/1/tests).

The regex is built under the asumption that no slashes ('/') can occur before the top level domain (except for the ones in 'http://')

Comment: Dang this is great. Thank you for your help. I think this is it - testing now. Added https: ^(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(\w*\.)*(cn)(\/.*)?$

Comment: @mlayt you can furthermore substitute '(http:\/\/|https:\/\/)' with '(https?:\/\/)' to shorten the regex.